# How do I deserialize only a property value from a JSON string?

Tags: c#, json

I'm experimenting with JWT auth in a Web API project, and this is the code that fetches the token:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var login = new {username = "mario", password = "secret"};
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var resp = await _client.PostAsync("api/Token", content);
    var json = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Yet the end value of `json` looks something like:

```
{ "token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUz...AXRbztetz_WhI"}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<???>(json);
```

but when I use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json)
```

I get a `JsonReaderException`:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line
>   1, position 1.

Now how do I deserialize that json to get the string value of the `token` property?

Comment: `var token = (string)JObject.Parse(json)["token"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
var token = (string)parsedJson["token"];
```

or

```
class TokenJsonResult{
  public string token {get;set;}
}

var parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenJsonResult>(json);
var token = parsedJson.token;
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first option is much simpler and works fine.

Comment: For me, it works with small amounts of JSON.
But, complex query results with many properties and object hierarchies, the second one does the job better.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an anonymous type to use as a template and read the properties like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var input = @"{'token':'eyJhbGciOiJIUzAXRbztetz_WhI'}";
var template = new { token = string.Empty };
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(input, template);
Console.WriteLine(result.token);
```

Output:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzAXRbztetz_WhI
```